# Drop row based on two columns conditions

Tags: python, pandas, row, multiple-columns

I have `dataframe` looks like this:

```
df
Data1   Data2   Data3
A       XX      AA
A       YY      AA
B       XX      BB
B       YY      CC
C       XX      DD
C       YY      DD
D       XX      EE
D       YY      FF
```

I want to delete all the row (column data3) based on two columns (data1 and data2) with the condition if the data on data3 is same the delete.

my expected result looks like this:

```
Data1   Data2   Data3
B       XX      BB
B       YY      CC
D       XX      EE
D       YY      FF
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `transform` with `nunique`

```
yd=df[df.groupby(['Data1']).Data3.transform('nunique').gt(1)].copy()
Out[506]: 
  Data1 Data2 Data3
2     B    XX    BB
3     B    YY    CC
6     D    XX    EE
7     D    YY    FF
```

Comment: Clever nice idea, +1

Comment: what is 'gt' means?

Comment: @Arief gt mean >

Comment: @Arief yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `groupby` with `nunique`, and a selection of rows:

```
>>> group = df.groupby('Data1')['Data3'].nunique()
>>> df[df['Data1'].isin(group[group.gt(1)].index)]
  Data1 Data2 Data3
2     B    XX    BB
3     B    YY    CC
6     D    XX    EE
7     D    YY    FF
>>>
```