# Drop row keep similiar value column data

Tags: python, pandas, row

Based on this question [Drop row based on two columns conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519823/drop-row-based-on-two-columns-conditions), otherwise, I want to eliminate the different value of row data.

I have `dataframe` looks like this:

```
df
Data1   Data2   Data3
A       XX      AA
A       YY      AA
B       XX      BB
B       YY      CC
C       XX      DD
C       YY      DD
D       XX      EE
D       YY      FF
```

my expected result looks like this:

```
Data1   Data2   Data3
A       XX      AA
A       YY      AA
C       XX      DD
C       YY      DD
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
df[df.groupby('Data1')['Data3'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
```

Or [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df[df.duplicated(['Data1','Data3'],keep=False)]
```

---

```
  Data1 Data2 Data3
0     A    XX    AA
1     A    YY    AA
4     C    XX    DD
5     C    YY    DD
```