# Drop row based in sequence two pair row data

Tags: python, pandas

Based on this question [Drop row based on two columns conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519823/drop-row-based-on-two-columns-conditions),  I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
Data1   Data2
A   first
A   last
B   first
B   last
C   first
C   last
D   first
D   last
B   first
D   last
B   last
```

I want to eliminate the data based on column Data 1 and Data 2 with the condition the same data deleted, and the third appeared is deleted. There are B and D of data in Data 1 column, which is the next B and D with no pair to the Data 2 column. I want to keep the pair of Data 1 and Data 2 in sequence.

My expected   result looks like this:

```
Data1   Data2
B   first
B   last
D   first
D   last
```

With detail:

```
Data1   Data2   Label
A   first   deleted
A   last    deleted
B   first   keep
B   last    keep
C   first   deleted
C   last    deleted
D   first   keep
D   last    keep
B   first   deleted
D   last    deleted
B   last    deleted
```

Forgive me for the inadequate explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? `duplicated` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df.loc[df.Data1.isin(df.loc[df.duplicated(),'Data1'])].drop_duplicates()
  Data1  Data2
2     B  first
3     B   last
6     D  first
7     D   last
```